# Break line an inline list

Tags: html, css

I have an inline list and I need to line break the list in two lines...

```
<ul>
    <li><h1><a href="#">One</a></h1></li>
    <li><h1><a href="#">Two</a></h1></li>
    <li><h1><a href="#">Three</a></h1></li>
    <li><h1><a href="#">Four</a></h1></li>
    <li><h1><a href="#">Five</a></h1></li>
    <li><h1><a href="#">Six</a></h1></li>
    <li><h1><a href="#">Seven</a></h1></li>
</ul>
```

Desire result:

**One Two Three Four < /br>
Five Six Seven**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about `float` and `clear`?

```
ul {overflow: hidden;}
li {float: left;}
li:nth-child(4) {clear: left;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hfc0u7e8/

Or if you don't want to float items and use, as you wrote, `display: inline`, you can use this code with `:before`:

```
ul {overflow: hidden;}
li, h1 {display: inline;}
li:nth-child(4):before {display: block; content: '';}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hfc0u7e8/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can this by using css like, here i have added div with cleat both to html to make children contained in ul.

```css
ul li{list-style:none; float:left;}
ul li:nth-child(5){clear:both;}
ul li h1 a{text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><h1><a href="#">One</a></h1></li>
    <li><h1><a href="#">Two</a></h1></li>
    <li><h1><a href="#">Three</a></h1></li>
    <li><h1><a href="#">Four</a></h1></li>
    <li><h1><a href="#">Five</a></h1></li>
    <li><h1><a href="#">Six</a></h1></li>
    <li><h1><a href="#">Seven</a></h1></li>
    <div style="clear:both;">
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Apparently splitting the list is undesired, so for a responsive list, just add a div around the lot and give it a suitable width:

html:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><h1><a href="#">One</a></h1></li>
    <li><h1><a href="#">Two</a></h1></li>
    <li><h1><a href="#">Three</a></h1></li>
    <li><h1><a href="#">Four</a></h1></li>
    <li><h1><a href="#">Five</a></h1></li>
    <li><h1><a href="#">Six</a></h1></li>
    <li><h1><a href="#">Seven</a></h1></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {list-style:none;}
li {display:inline-block;}
div {float:left; width:60%;}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5yrsqdv0/1/)

Comment: Totally inneficient way imho

Comment: @SHAMAN Two lines of css and no styling in the html. In what way is it inefficient?

Comment: @MarkHamill: what about eg. responsive design, when I'll need to show two items in a row? It's impossible with your code. Design things should be done in the CSS, not divide one UL into two while I need just one list.

Comment: @panther OP only asked how to split a list into two rows, not how to make the list responsive to width. A responsive width can be made by putting the list into div with a suitable width: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yrsqdv0/1/)

Comment: @MarkHamill: it was just an example. There is no reason to divide one UL into two ULs. This is task for css, not html

Comment: Splitting ULs is simplest way to ahcieve what the OP asked for, it results in the least amount of extra code. I changed my answer anyway, the new answer is responsive to width.